# How to "virtually" tap back button in Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol, uicontainerview

I have app, where is Segmented Control inside of my Navigation Bar. Under navigation bar I have 3 containers. In these containers I have Table View Controllers. If you tap on segmented control, one TVC appear and others disappear (container1.hidden = true and so on).

Problem is when I press "save" button which is also in navigation controller - button doesn't trigger "virtual push of back button".

I used following code which works in my other projects (its in button's action which is in VC that contains all container views) but not this time:

```
if let navController = self.navigationController {
   navController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Image for better insight:
[image]

**UPDATE**: Thanks to @ Alexey Bondarchuk I solved it. Comments may be confusing so I just recap problem and solution.

Originally, I had ViewController. To this controller I embed in Navigation Controller. To this Navigation Controller I connected segues. And that was mistake. 
So I deleted this embed in navigation controller, made (show) segues directly to my View Controller (which is on screenshot). This automatically created navigation bar and last thing I did was that I put **navigation item** in it so now my code pop right navigationController. Hope that it's understandable.

Comment: Can you post more code ? Specially where the popViewControllerAnimated is located in context ?

Comment: Sure, I updated my question. Thanks:)

Comment: Did you check if it jumps in the if condition and the navigationController ist set ? If so, then check if the navigationController that pushed that content thats currently visible is the same as `self.navigationController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have couple ideas:

1. Your navigationController equal to 'nil' and `.popViewControllerAnimated` will never invoked. This may happen if you are using UITabBarController. In this case try to use `self.tabBarController?.navigationController` instead of `self.navigationController`.
2. Your controller presented 'Modally'. In this case you can try to invoke `navController.dismissViewControllerAnimated`instead of `navController.popViewControllerAnimated`

Comment: navigationController is not equal to nil (tested). also i dont use UITabBarController (in my previous project i do, and `self.navigationController.pop...` works fine), but i use UIViewController. im starting to be really desperate

Comment: @Lachtan 1. Have you tried to .dismissViewControllerAnimated? 2. Can you remove `if let navController = self.navigationController` and invoke .popViewControllerAnimated directly? 3. I need more info about your hierarchy, can you do this?

Comment: Also can you print  `self.navigationController?.parentViewController`?

Comment: I can. Console: `Optional(<UINavigationController: 0x7fb029da4430>)`. But still doesnt work. My hierarchy is simple. I have ViewController (+ editor - embeded in -  navigation controller). Inside this VC I have 3 container views. When I press Uložit (~save) button, I want to save data and go back to Table View Controller containing list of saved items.

Comment: @Lachtan 1. Can you create snapshot like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wgmgpt6w3rq6cln/Screen%20Shot%202015-08-18%20at%2018.03.44.png?dl=0)? This will help me to figure out the problem. 2. Does Záznamy back to previous controller?

Comment: Thanks !! I finally solved it. I deleted Navigation Controller (created from edit - embeded in - Navigation Bar) and then I made segues directly to my VC (and added Navigation Item into newly created navigation bar). Thank you very much for help

Comment: @Lachtan You are welcome, but looks like you solve it by yourself with a small rework :)